# How to read from or write to a scoketConnection? (newbie)

Tags: rcpp

I never have used C++ before so this may be a dumb question.

In R I use this function to read from a socket:

```
socket_bin_reader <- function(in_sock) {
  string_read <- raw(0)
  while((rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n=1)) > 0) {
    if (rd == 0xff) rd <- readBin(in_sock, what = "raw", n =1)
    string_read <- c(string_read, rd)
  }
  return(string_read)
}
```

This functions does exactly what I need, but has the disadvantage that it takes a lot of time to read large quantities of data. Therefore I am looking for ways to use C++.

I found this example on how to read byte-by-byte from a file ([cpp-byte-file-reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625115/cpp-byte-file-reading))
The body from my function will probably be based on this example. My guess is that it will look like:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector socket_bin_reader_C(??? in_sock) {
  NumericVector out = NumericVector::create(??);
  ifstream infile(in_sock, ios::in | ios::binary);
  while (rd = infile.read(char*) > 0) {
    if (rd == 0xff) rd = infile.read(char*);
    add rd to out;
  }
}
```

But I have two questions:

1. In Rcpp you have to provide a class for each parameter. What is the class for a socketConnection?
2. I know that in C or C++ you have to allocate memory. How can I dynamically reallocate more memory for the return vector?

Ben

Comment: It is really the same as in plain C or C++.  You can't pass the _connection_ itself, you pass the name of connection (file, urlm or here socket) and then open that in your C(++) snippet called from R via Rcpp.

Comment: Does that mean that after every read or write you have to close the connection? In the present situation, I first create an instance of a R6-class, add a field that points to a socketConnection (which remains open for as long as the session lasts) and the authenticate the connection. I can imagine that with files, it may make sense to open/close the file every time I used it, but with a socket this is not very convenient.